# Fit a time series in python with a mean value as boundary condition

Tags: python, time-series

I have the following boundary conditions for a time series in python. 
The notation I use here is t_x, where x describe the time in milliseconds (this is not my code, I just thought this notation is good to explain my issue).

```py
t_0 = 0 
t_440 = -1.6
t_830 = 0
mean_value = -0.6
```

I want to create a list that contains 83 values (so the spacing is 10ms for each value).
**The list should descibe a "curve"** that starts at zero, has the minimum value of -1.6 at 440ms (so 44 in the list), ends with 0 at 880ms (so 83 in the list) **and the overall mean value of the list should be -0.6.**

I absolutely could not come up with an idea how to "fit" the boundaries to create such a list.

I would really appreciate help.

Comment: Must the values be strictly decreasing before index 44, and strictly increasing after? Also, what restrictions are on the "curve", or any arrangement of points is fine?  
I mean, all your unknown values can be (-0.6 * 84 + 1.6) / 81 = -0.6024691358024691 and that would satisfy the mean condition.

Comment: Yes the values should be strictly decreasing before 44 and after. 
The process is describing physics of a moving object so the curve should be smooth in the best case. My example with the numbers is also just an example and I would love to have a generic solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a quick and dirty approach, but it works:

```
X = list(range(0, 830 +1, 10))
Y = [0.0 for x in X]
Y[44] = -1.6
b = 12.3486
for x in range(44):
    Y[x] = -1.6*(b*x+x**2)/(b*44+44**2)  
for x in range(83, 44, -1):
    Y[x] = -1.6*(b*(83-x)+(83-x)**2)/(b*38+38**2)  
print(f'{sum(Y)/len(Y)=:8.6f}, {Y[0]=}, {Y[44]=}, {Y[83]=}')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

With the code giving following output:

```
sum(Y)/len(Y)=-0.600000, Y[0]=-0.0, Y[44]=-1.6, Y[83]=-0.0
```

And showing following diagram:

[image: XYplot-1]

The first step in coming up with the above approach was to create a linear sloping 'curve' from the minimum to the zeroes. I turned out that linear approach gives here too large mean Y value what means that the 'curve' must have a sharp peak at its minimum and need to be approached with a polynomial. To make things simple I decided to use quadratic polynomial and approach the minimum from left and right side separately as the curve isn't symmetric. The b-value was found by trial and error and its precision can be increased manually or by writing a small function finding it in an iterative way.

**Update providing a *generic* solution as requested in a comment**

The code below provides a

*`meanYboundaryXY(lbc = [(0,0), (440,-1.6), (830,0), -0.6], shape='saw')`*

function returning the X and Y lists of the time series data calculated from the passed parameter with the boundary values:

```
def meanYboundaryXY(lbc = [(0,0), (440,-1.6), (830,0), -0.6]): 
    lbcXY = lbc[0:3] ; meanY_boundary = lbc[3]
    minX = min(x for x,y in lbcXY)
    maxX = max(x for x,y in lbcXY)
    minY = lbc[1][1]
    step = 10
    X = list(range(minX, maxX + 1, step))
    lenX = len(X) 
    Y = [None for x in X]
    sumY = 0
    for x, y in lbcXY:
        Y[x//step] = y
        sumY += y
    target_sumY = meanY_boundary*lenX

    if shape == 'rect': 
        subY = (target_sumY-sumY)/(lenX-3)
        for i, y in enumerate(Y):
            if y is None:
                Y[i] = subY
    elif shape == 'saw':
        peakNextY = 2*(target_sumY-sumY)/(lenX-1)
        iYleft  = lbc[1][0]//step-1
        iYrght  = iYleft+2
        iYstart = lbc[0][0] // step
        iYend   = lbc[2][0] // step
        for i in range(iYstart, iYleft+1, 1):
            Y[i] = peakNextY * i / iYleft  
        for i in range(iYend, iYrght-1, -1):
            Y[i] = peakNextY * (iYend-i)/(iYend-iYrght)  
    else: 
        raise ValueError( str(f'meanYboundaryXY() EXIT, {shape=} not in ["saw","rect"]') )

    return (X, Y)

X, Y = meanYboundaryXY()

print(f'{sum(Y)/len(Y)=:8.6f}, {Y[0]=}, {Y[44]=}, {Y[83]=}')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

The code outputs:

```
sum(Y)/len(Y)=-0.600000, Y[0]=0, Y[44]=-1.6, Y[83]=0
```

and creates following two diagrams for `shape='rect'` and `shape='saw'`:

[image: XYplot-2]

[image: XYplot-3]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Did you come up with the b value and "38" value by try and error?
Unfortunately I would need a generic version of fitting this, my numbers were only one example.
But you solution is very interesting, how did you come up with the polynoms or form? Do you have a key word perhaps regarding the algorithm you used?
Thank you :)

Comment: The '38' value is the number of list items to set values for. The b-value can be found iterative. A generic version of fitting this should consider higher order polynomials for smaller absolute mean values and the polynomials 'other way around' for large absolute mean values. As the mean Y value can probably be obtained by derivation you should ask better in the mathematical methods group for a generic solution as it has nothing to do with programming stackoverflow is about.

Comment: By the way: your boundary conditions for the 'curve' let much room for guessing. If you want a quick and dirty generic solution ... the 'curve' will be a not well looking one ... probably not what you are after. Right? And if the 'curve' can be any one ... the solution is trivial to achieve in a deterministic way without iterations.

Comment: See updated answer for the *generic solution*.

Answer (score 0):

As an old geek, i try to solve the question with **a simple algorithm**.
First calculate points as two symmetric lines from 0 to 44 and 44 to 89 (orange on the graph).
Calculate sum except middle point and its ratio with sum of points when mean is -0.6, except middle point.
Apply ratio to previous points except middle point. (blue curve on the graph)
Obtain curve which was called "saw" by Claudio.
For my own, i think quadratic interpolation of Claudio is a better curve, but needs trial and error loops.

```
import matplotlib

# define goals
nbPoints = 89
msPerPoint = 10
midPoint = nbPoints//2
valueMidPoint = -1.6
meanGoal = -0.6


def createSerieLinear():
    # two lines 0 up to 44, 44 down to 88 (89 values centered on 44)
    serie=[0 for i in range(0,nbPoints)]
    interval =valueMidPoint/midPoint
    for i in range(0,midPoint+1):
        serie[i]=i*interval
        serie[nbPoints-1-i]=i*interval
    return serie

# keep an original to plot
orange = createSerieLinear()
# work on a base
base = createSerieLinear()

# total except midPoint
totalBase = (sum(base)-valueMidPoint) 
#total goal except 44
totalGoal = meanGoal*nbPoints - valueMidPoint 

# apply ratio to reduce 
reduceRatio = totalGoal/totalBase
for i in range(0,midPoint):
    base[i] *= reduceRatio
    base[nbPoints-1-i] *= reduceRatio 
 

# verify 
meanBase = sum(base)/nbPoints 
print("new mean:",meanBase)


# draw 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
X =[i*msPerPoint for i in range(0,nbPoints)]
plt.plot(X,base)
plt.plot(X,orange)
plt.show()
```

```
new mean: -0.5999999999999998
```

[image]

Hope you enjoy simple things :)